# Return XHR value in C# (Script Task SSIS)

Tags: c#, ssis, script-task

I'm trying to get the value from a XHR e.g. http://www.mypage.com/step/make/validateuser.php?user=test456&password=test123.

I was testing with HttpWebResponse and other ways that I find here, but without success. The code below was the last tested, and don't return the string text expected by the link XHR.

````
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://www.mypage.com/step/make/validateuser.php?user=test456&password=test123");
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string responseString;
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    responseString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    MessageBox.Show(responseString);
                }
            }

            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a fan of the `MessageBox.Show()`.  It would be much better to set a breakpoint and step through it to see the value of responseString, reader, and response while it is running.

Comment: Thanks Randy, I could get the message with breakpoint. Was a proxy authentication issue solved with IWebProxy: `IWebProxy proxy = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Proxy = proxy;`